# How to do show list of an Item in alexa skill using Alexa.Net.APL?

Tags: c#

I am trying to display list of item on Echo show. Am using Alexa.Net.APL C# and below is what i have done so far but is not displaying i will appreciate help.

This is my method that generate Directive

```
private RenderDocumentDirective BuildDirective(string bg = "")
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bg))
        {
            bg = "https://i.ibb.co/5cWztFH/brown-on-seashore-near-mountain-1007657.jpg";

        }
        var mainLayout = new Layout(
            new AlexaTextList
            {
                BackgroundImageSource = bg,
                HeaderTitle = "Alexa text list header title",
                HeaderSubtitle = "sub",
                HeaderDivider = true,
                BackgroundScale = new APLValue<Scale>(Scale.BestFill),
                BackgroundAlign = new APLValue<string>("center"),
                BackgroundColor = new APLValue<string>("transparent"),
                ListItems = new APLValue<List<AlexaTextListItem>>()
                {
                    Value = new List<AlexaTextListItem>
                            {
                                new AlexaTextListItem
                                {
                                    PrimaryText = "Hello world! 1"
                                },
                                new AlexaTextListItem
                                {
                                    PrimaryText = "Hello world! 2"
                                },
                                new AlexaTextListItem
                                {
                                    PrimaryText = "Hello world! 3"
                                }
                            }
                }
            }
        );
        var renderDocument = new RenderDocumentDirective
        {
            Token = "randomToken",
            Document = new APLDocument
            {
                MainTemplate = mainLayout
            },
            

        };
        return renderDocument;
    }
```

Here is where am calling it

```
var response = ResponseBuilder.Ask(d, rp, session);
                    var dr = BuildDirective();
                    response.Response.Directives.Add(dr);
                    return response;
```

Comment: did you add the permisson to access the screen in your skill's permisson tab?

Comment: Yes I have other directives that is displaying fine. what am having issue with is displaying list of an item